# How to pass a callback method from JavaScript to java back-end with spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I am writing a code which can be accessed using jsonp. I need to pass a callback method from java script to spring boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@ControllerAdvice`

For more detail, visit [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

Answer (score 1):

use ControllerAdvice

```
 @ControllerAdvice
    static class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

        public JsonpAdvice() {
            super("callback");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @ControllerAdvice in spring boot